# How to pass the UI Dispatcher to the ViewModel 

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

I'm supposed to be able to access the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) that belongs to the View I need to pass it to the ViewModel. But the View should not know anything about the ViewModel, so how do you pass it? Introduce an interface or instead of passing it to the instances create a global dispatcher singleton that will be written by the View? How do you solve this in your MVVM applications and frameworks?

EDIT: Note that since my ViewModels might be created in background threads I can't just do `Dispatcher.Current` in the constructor of the ViewModel.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have abstracted the Dispatcher using an interface *IContext*:

```cs
public interface IContext
{
   bool IsSynchronized { get; }
   void Invoke(Action action);
   void BeginInvoke(Action action);
}
```

This has the advantage that you can unit-test your ViewModels more easily. 
I inject the interface into my ViewModels using the MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework). Another possibility would be a constructor argument.
However, I like the injection using MEF more.

**Update (example from pastebin link in comments):**

```cs
public sealed class WpfContext : IContext
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get
        {
            return this._dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread;
        }
    }

    public WpfContext() : this(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher)
    {
    }

    public WpfContext(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        Debug.Assert(dispatcher != null);

        this._dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Debug.Assert(action != null);

        this._dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }

    public void BeginInvoke(Action action)
    {
        Debug.Assert(action != null);

        this._dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of an implementation in a wpf UserControl?

Comment: Yes, any examples can be provided on the implementation? thanks.

Answer (score 47):

why would not you use

```
 System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
         (Action)(() => {ObservableCollectionMemeberOfVM.Add("xx"); } ));
```

instead of keeping reference to GUI dispatcher.

Comment: Strangly Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher didn't work for me. Application.Current.Dispatcher worked.

Answer (score 19):

You may not actually need the dispatcher.  If you bind properties on your viewmodel to GUI elements in your view, the WPF binding mechanism automatically marshals the GUI updates to the GUI thread using the dispatcher.

---

**EDIT:**

This edit is in response to Isak Savo's comment.

Inside Microsoft's code for handling binding to properties you will find the following code:

```
if (Dispatcher.Thread == Thread.CurrentThread)
{ 
    PW.OnPropertyChangedAtLevel(level);
} 
else 
{
    // otherwise invoke an operation to do the work on the right context 
    SetTransferIsPending(true);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
        new DispatcherOperationCallback(ScheduleTransferOperation), 
        new object[]{o, propName});
}
```

This code marshals any UI updates to the thread UI thread so that even if you update the properties taking part of the binding from a different thread, WPF will automatically serialize the call to the UI thread.

Comment: but there are plenty of situations, you might need to do this, Imagine an ObservableCollection bound to the UI and you trying to call _collection.Add() from a worker thread

Comment: I know. Of course, the usual theading considerations still apply.

Comment: Currently we need the dispatcher for the sole purpose of adding items to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you jakob, this is completely wrong. The binding mechanism won't do any marshalling for you. If you update a property in the view model from a background thread, the NotifyPropertyChanged event will be raised on that background thread and the GUI will be updated on that background thread -> exception! -1 until someone proves me wrong

Comment: Hi Isak. You understand me correctly but you are wrong. If you debug through Microsoft's WPF binding code (or look at it using Reflector), you will see that the code checks if you are on the GUI thread and if not it will use the Dispatcher to update on the GUI thread.  I don't know if it works for ObservableCollection but it does for "normal" properties. I wrote a blog entry on this (in Danish though). At the bottom of the blog entry Microsoft's code is shown: http://www.dotninjas.dk/post/Flere-trade-og-binding-i-WPF.aspx

Comment: Jakob: You are absolutely correct. I've modified my -1 to +1 instead. I tried this in both .net 3.5 and 4.0 and it seems it's perfectly ok to raise PropertyChanged on a background thread.

Comment: This isn't true for Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 at least. I raised my property changed event in the background thread and got the cross-thread exception.

Answer (score 17):

I get the ViewModel to store the current dispatcher as a member.

If the ViewModel is created by the view, you know that the current dispatcher at creation time will be the View's dispatcher.

```
class MyViewModel
{
    readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my scenario the ViewModels are created in threads. That's why I was asking in the first place.

Comment: But problematic for unit testing. How do you write this sort of code and unit test your VMs?

Comment: @Roy: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests/1303762#1303762

Comment: Yeah, DispatcherFrame makes your unit tests clunky and horrible to write.  Why not just abstract it away?

Answer (score 7):

As of MVVM Light 5.2, the library now includes a `DispatcherHelper` class in `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading` namespace that exposes a function `CheckBeginInvokeOnUI()` that accepts a delegate and runs it on the UI thread. Comes in very handy if your ViewModel is running some worker threads which affect VM properties to which your UI elements are bound.

`DispatcherHelper` must be initialized by calling `DispatcherHelper.Initialize()` at an early stage in the life of your application (e.g. `App_Startup`). You can then run any delegate (or lambda) using the following call:

```
DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(
        () =>
        {
           //Your code here
        });
```

Note that the class is defined in `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform` library which is not referenced by default when you add it through NuGet. You must manually add a reference to this lib.

Comment: DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI used but datagrid load large amount of Data then UI hang  why?

Comment: `DispatcherHelper` is only meant to marshal your calls across to the UI thread. You use it AFTER your worker thread has finished the job. It doesn't magically reduce load times, nor does it somehow make the `DataGrid` load data any faster. It just gets rid of the infamous "illegal cross-thread call to the UI" exception. For improving your UI responsiveness, look into `async`/`await` pattern along with virtualization support in WPF `DataGrid`.

Comment: Datagrid load data very slow using observable collection

Comment: Do not load thousands of rows in the grid at the same time. Also if you do not need cell level editing, you may better be off using a standard `ListBox`. If you must use `DataGrid`, use some sort of paging to minimize the amount of data you need to show at a time.

Comment: BTW, post a new question if you need help for your particular scenario. Comments are only supposed to be related to the posted question or answer or making it better in some respect.

Comment: Ok Thank You Please Tell me Perfect Way to used DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI in Coding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226173/discussion-between-ghotekar-rahul-and-dotnet).

Answer (score 5):

Another common pattern (which is seeing much use now in the framework) is the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx).

It enables you to dispatch synchronously and asynchronously.  You can also set the current SynchronizationContext on the current thread, meaning it is easily mocked.  The DispatcherSynchronizationContext is used by WPF apps.  Other implementations of the SynchronizationContext are used by WCF and WF4.

Comment: This is the best and easiest method, I think. You can default the ViewModel's SynchronizationContext to the thread's current context in which the ViewModel was created, and, if a UserControl needs to change it, they can change it at will.

Answer (score 3):

As of WPF version 4.5 one can use [CurrentDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Do GUI related operations here

}, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

Comment: This singleton doesn't work very well in multithreaded scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only needing the dispatcher for modifying a bound collection in another thread take a look at the SynchronizationContextCollection here http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/01/cross-thread-collection-binding-in-wpf.html

Works well, only issue I found is when using View Models with SynchronizationContextCollection properties with ASP.NET synch context, but easily worked around.

HTH
Sam

Answer (score 1):

hi maybe i am too late since it has been 8 months since your first post...
i had the same proble in a silverlight mvvm applicatioin. and i found my solution like this. for each model and viewmodel that i have, i have also a class called controller.
like that

```
public class MainView : UserControl  // (because it is a silverlight user controll)
public class MainViewModel
public class MainController
```

my MainController is in charge of the commanding and the connection between the model and viewmodel. in the constructor i instanciate the view and its viewmodel and set the datacontext of the view to its viewmodel.

```
mMainView = new MainView();
mMainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
mMainView.DataContext = mMainViewModel;
```

//(in my naming convention i have a prefix m for member variables)

i also have a public property in the type of my MainView. like that

```
public MainView View { get { return mMainView; } }
```

(this mMainView is a local variable for the public property)

and now i am done. i just need to use my dispatcher for my ui therad like this...

```
mMainView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    () => MessageBox.Show(mSpWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName));
```

(in this example i was asking my controller to get my sharepoint 2010 loginname but you can do what your need)

we are almost done you also need to define your root visual in the app.xaml like this

```
var mainController = new MainController();
RootVisual = mainController.View;
```

this helped me by my application. maybe it can help you too...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the UI Dispatcher to the ViewModel.
The UI Dispatcher is available from the current application singleton.

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher
```

This will make your ViewModel dependent on the View. Depending on your application, that may or may not be fine.

Answer (score 1):

for WPF and Windows store apps use:-

```
       System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => {ObservableCollectionMemeberOfVM.Add("xx"); } ));
```

keeping reference to GUI dispatcher is not really the right way.

if that doesn't work (such as in case of windows phone 8 apps) then use:-

```
       Deployment.Current.Dispatcher
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are used [uNhAddIns](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins) you can make an asynchrounous behavior easily. take a look [here](http://hemocoid.blogspot.com/2010/10/extending-unhaddins-componentbehavior.html)

And i think need a few modification to make it work on Castle Windsor (without uNhAddIns)

Answer (score 0):

I've find another (most simplest) way:

Add to view model action that's should be call in Dispatcher:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Action<Action> CallWithDispatcher;

    public void SomeMultithreadMethod()
    {
        if(CallWithDispatcher != null)
            CallWithDispatcher(() => DoSomethingMetod(SomeParameters));
    }
}
```

And add this action handler in view constructor:

```
    public View()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();

        DataContext = model;
        InitializeComponent();

        // Here 
        model.CallWithDispatcher += act => _taskbarIcon.Dispatcher
            .BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, act) ;
    }
```

Now you haven't problem with testing, and it's easy to implement.
I've add it to my [site](http://molodih.org.ua/?t=78)

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass dispatcher when you can access application dispatcher using

```
Dispatcher dis = Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

Answer (score -1):

Some of my WPF projects I have faced the same situation.  In my MainViewModel (Singleton instance), I got my CreateInstance() static method takes the dispatcher.  And the create instance gets called from the View so that I can pass the Dispatcher from there. 
And the ViewModel test module calls CreateInstance() parameterless.

But in a complex multithread scenario it is always good to have an interface implementation on the View side so as to get the proper Dispatcher of the current Window.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am a bit late to this discussion, but I found 1 nice article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx

There is 1 paragraph

> Furthermore, all code outside the View layer (that is, the ViewModel
>   and Model layers, services, and so on) should not depend on any type
>   tied to a specific UI platform. Any direct use of Dispatcher
>   (WPF/Xamarin/Windows Phone/Silverlight), CoreDispatcher (Windows
>   Store), or ISynchronizeInvoke (Windows Forms) is a bad idea.
>   (SynchronizationContext is marginally better, but barely.) For
>   example, there’s a lot of code on the Internet that does some
>   asynchronous work and then uses Dispatcher to update the UI; a more
>   portable and less cumbersome solution is to use await for asynchronous
>   work and update the UI without using Dispatcher.

Assume if you can use async/await properly, this is not an issue.