# Running multiple C# Task Async

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, c#-4.0

Hi normally I would do this with a Background Worker, but I would like to do it with C# Task instead, just to understand Task better.

The thing is that I have a class with the following properties

```
    private int _number1;
    public int Number1
    {
        get { return _number1; }
        set { _number1 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Number1");}
    }

    private int _number2;
    public int Number2
    {
        get { return _number2; }
        set { _number2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("Number2");}
    }
```

Please note that I use the INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
Number1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult()).Result;
Number2 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult2()).Result;
```

The GenerateResult and GenerateResult2 are just dumme methods, who sleeps and then return a number.

How would I make this work Async? Since right now, GenerateResult2() is first called when GenerateResult() is finished.

I need it to be able work Async, since I have no idea of when each task is going to finish or even if its going to finish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you get the `Result` property, you are effectively waiting for the task to complete. It will execute on a background thread but you are waiting in your main thread for the completion before you start the next thread.

See the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) for details.

You should be able to just assign your properties from the background thread:

```
Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => Number1 = GenerateResult());
```

WPF databinding will [take care of marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354438/mvvm-best-practice-to-pass-dispatcher-to-the-viewmodel/2354674#2354674) the PropertyChanged event to the correct dispatcher thread.

Comment: Thanks alot Isak Savo workes perfect and is simple to read :-) Alot easier then Backgroundworkers

Comment: It is not definite that any Task will execute all the time on a worker thread. Result simply blocks the thread which called it until it is ready to output the data or set an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I had a debug line that was calling .Result so I could do a quick test and it was breaking the async :O

Answer (score 3):

I checked this: [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) and it it states that when using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>` the Tasks run asynchronously and may complete in any order. *If Result is accessed before the computation completes, the property will block the thread until the value is available.*

I think that means if you are accessing `.Result` before it has a value, as you are doing in your sample code, you will have to wait for it to complete first.

It does make sense as the `Result` property would not be populated until the Task is completed.

Comment: Didn't see Isak Savo's answer which already points out that accessing Result will wait for task to complete.

Answer (score -3):

```
Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateResult2()).ContinueWith(() => GenerateResult());
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is exactly the same semantics as the OP's code - the second task isn't started until the first has completed.