# Asynchronous Threading

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I would please like to know where I can get an example of multithreading or asynchronous threading.

In the application that I am busy with I have to run a thread in the background of my application to fetch a value that is changing. And whenever this value reaches a certain amount then it needs to call another function. All this has to run in the background of the program so that the user can still do something else on the application.

Any examples or links that could help would really be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: background worker? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Async *and* threading?  You really have a thing for not knowing when your code's gonna run, don't you.  :)

Comment: I second the suggestion of http://www.albahari.com/threading/ (that's by the guy who wrote LinqPad, I think)

Answer (score 3):

In order to summarize the options, I will try to list them here (maybe it would be a good idea to make this a community wiki).

First of all, you can simply start a function in another [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx):

```
Thread t = new Thread( ThreadProc );
t.Start();
// now you can wait for thread to finish with t.Join() or just continue
// Thread.IsBackground allows to control how thread lifetime influences
// the lifetime of the application

...
static void ThreadProc() {...} // can also be non-static, but for simplicity....
```

Then you can use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx):

```
BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
bgWorker.DoWork += MyFunction;
bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

voud MyFunction(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args) {...}
```

You can use `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events for more control (as well as `WorkerReportsProgress` and other properties)

Another option is to use [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), if your method will not take too much time:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc));
...
static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo) { ... }
```

Yet another option is to call [`BeginInvoke` on a delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx):

```
public delegate int MyDelegate(...);

MyDelegate del = SomeFunction;                     
IAsyncResult ar = del.BeginInvoke(...);
int result = del.EndInvoke(ar);
```

This will execute on a thread from the thread pool. If you need to wait on calling thread, you can use `IAsyncResult.IsCompleted`, but it will block the calling thread.

And of course, you can use [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx):

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod());
```

This will also execute `MyMethod` on a thread from the thread pool, so the same warnings apply (although you can use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to ensure that the new thread is always created). Under some circumstances (when you wait on task) it can even execute on the same thread, but it is well optimized so you should not worry about that.

This is probably the option with best tradeoff of simplicity vs control (of course, there is no really 'the best'). Here are the benefits (shamelessly stolen from [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889789/1663919)):

- Adding continuations (Task.ContinueWith)
- Waiting for multiple tasks to complete (either all or any)
- Capturing errors in the task and interrogating them later
- Capturing cancellation (and allowing you to specify cancellation to start with)
- Potentially having a return value
- Using await in C# 5
- Better control over scheduling (if it's going to be long-running, say so when you create the task so the task scheduler can take that into account)

Comment: Awesomely descriptive and totally destroys my answer +1 to you good sir.

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on the level of control that you seek a `BackgroundWorker` could easily work and its found within the `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`. Now here is a link to the MSDN docs on the subject matter :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

a Simple usecase secenario is like so:

```
BackgrouWorker BG = new BackgroudWorker();
GB.DoWork += YourFunctionDelegate(object Sender, EventArgs e);
GB.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Now `YourFunctionDelegate(object Sender,EventArgs e)` should be what ever it is you want run in the background. However needs to follow this argument form, There are also a good amount of helper functions associated with the backgroundworker like `onProgressChanged` event that allows monitoring of obviously progress, which if you are new to threading can prove to be a pain at first if you try to make your own threads.

If you would like more control over execution and how the threads function you should take a look at the Task-Parallel-Library here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx Which has copious amount of information about multi-threading.

Also here is a great tutorial on how to create a C# thread: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;815804

Answer (score 1):

For an overview of asynchronous programming on Windows 8 in .Net 4.5:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

For .Net 4.0 and older you can use the ThreadPool

```
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj =>
    {
        // Do some work
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            Math.Sin(i);

        // Get back to the UI thread
        App.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new Action(delegate 
            { 
                block.Text = "Done!"; 
            }));
    });
```

Comment: For .net 4, TPL and it's Tasks are the preferred way to achieve parallelism http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post that [compares and contrasts various implementations of background tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html), with advantages and disadvantages for each. Spoiler: `Task` is definitely the best option. Also, I recommend `Task.Run` over `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

If your background operation is truly asynchronous, then you may not need any background threading at all. LINQPad has a [set of `async` examples](http://www.linqpad.net/RichClient/SampleLibraries.aspx) that are a great starting point. These are more up-to-date than the chapter on threading (by the same author) that others have recommended.