# Application.Current.Dispatcher vs DependencyObject.Dispatcher for UI Thread Access

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I usually exclusively use **`Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`** when I need to access the UI thread but is there an appropriate time to use **`someDependencyObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)`**

I am assuming all the DependencyObjects/UIElements are created on the UI thread so the final result should be the same or similar.

- What is the difference (if any) between the calls?
- Is there a rule on when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all `DispatcherObject` instances are necessarily created on the primary UI thread (some applications use a thread per `Window` approach).

I would personally advise using `DispatcherObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` as regardless of which thread created the entity, the use of the `DispatcherObject` in the delegate will succeed.

```
// Will always work
myTextBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(myTextBox.Focus));
```

With `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, the use of the `DispatcherObject` may fail if the instance was created on a different thread.

```
// May fail if myTextBox was created on a different thread
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(myTextBox.Focus));
```

Comment: But @Lukazoid:
We cant have the control references in the ViewModel rite?
and from there if I need to do something in the UI Thread. then What to do?

Comment: @Arijit That sounds like another question, such as this one: [How to pass the UI Dispatcher to the ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354438/how-to-pass-the-ui-dispatcher-to-the-viewmodel), see if that addresses your question, if not search for a question like yours and if none exists, ask a new question.