# DataGrid update not working when changed source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my DataGrid testing code. I set some data on the DataGrid source with ObservableCollection and bound this. And I modify the value where the ObservableCollection member's property. In this case, my UI has to show that value is changed. However, my DataGrid only interact when I selected the cell.

**Binding**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> griddata { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
```

**My Class**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public int idxnumber { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding griddata, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**Function**

```
//... griddata.add(someOfData);
public void ViewModel()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 30)
    {
        testing(0);
        i++;
    }
}

private void testing(int idxnum)
{
    var test = griddata.Where(z => z.idxnumber == idxnum).FirstOrDefalut();
    test.num += 1;
}
```

**Result** 
Cell value shows that `0` and I selected value is changed to `30`, immediately.

**Expect result** 
Cell value shows `0` to `30` continuously.

**EDIT :** 
This is my whole code:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSol3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSol3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding griddata}">
            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Model.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSol3
{
    public class Model
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public int idxnumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestSol3
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> griddata { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            griddata.Add(new Model() { num = 0, idxnumber = 0 });
            griddata.Add(new Model() { num = 1, idxnumber = 1 });

            Load(0);
        }

        private void Load(int idxnum)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(i < 30)
            {
                i++;
                griddata[idxnum].num++;
                //Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add ```Thread.Sleep(100);``` in ```while (i < 30)``` will slow down the value update speed in the UI

Comment: @cg-zhou Not work.  I tried `Thread.sleep()` and `Task.Delay` also but It does not help this.

Comment: I've tried to build a project by you description, and it seems hard because partial code missing; If you provide runable xx.xaml.cs and xx.cs, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your model

```
namespace TestSol3
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Model> _griddata = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        public ObservableCollection<Model> griddata 
        { 
            get => _griddata;
            set
            {
                _griddata= value;
                OnChangedProperty("griddata");
            }
        }

        public void OnChangedProperty(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Solution]**

In WPF, you can get `dispatcher` from `Application.Current.Dispatcher`

[How to pass the UI Dispatcher to the ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354438/how-to-pass-the-ui-dispatcher-to-the-viewmodel)

And we need to change items in `ObservableCollection` to notify value change events.

The document of `ObservableCollection` says:

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0

```
private void Load(int idxnum)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 30)
        {
            i++;
            var model = griddata[idxnum];
            model.num++;

            var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                griddata.RemoveAt(idxnum);
                griddata.Insert(idxnum, model);
            });

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    });
}
```

**[Simple Demo]**

I wrote a demo project to show how to update UI value continuously as below.

It use `Task` to start another thread to update UI value, hope it helps.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">        

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Start</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Task? CurrentTask { get; set; }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // only one task is supported simultaneously
            if (this.CurrentTask != null
                && !this.CurrentTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                return;
            }

            // start a task to calculate value continuously
            this.CurrentTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 30)
                {
                    ++i;
                    Thread.Sleep(500);

                    // update value in the UI thread
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        this.MyTextBlock.Text = i.ToString();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this.

Comment: I found the biggest issue with this answer. Sorry for this answer, Text block works well used `dispatcher` but `DataGrid` is not work well when the property changes continuously.

Comment: I updated the answer, the ```ObservableCollection``` only accepts ```add/remove/refresh``` events.

Comment: I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427471/observablecollection-not-noticing-when-item-in-it-changes-even-with-inotifyprop)