# Propagate exception thrown in continuation task when invoking dispatcher from unit test

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

I have the following code executing in a unit test:

```
        var continueScheduler = new CurrentThreadScheduler();
        var task = Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() => { })
            .ContinueWith(obj => { throw new Exception("Fail"); }, continueScheduler);

        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
```

`StartNew()` starts a new thread where the empty action is executed. The `CurrentThreadScheduler` then makes sure that the `ContinueWith()` action is made on the main thread:

```
    public class CurrentThreadScheduler : TaskScheduler
    {
        private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        public CurrentThreadScheduler()
        {
            _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }

        protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
        {
            _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(() => TryExecuteTask(task)));
        }

        protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Task>();
        }
    }
```

The `while` loop waits for the task (including `ContinueWith()`) to finish. Here's the `DoEvents()` code:

```
    private static void DoEvents()
    {
        var frame = new DispatcherFrame();
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrame), frame);
        Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
    }

    private static object ExitFrame(object frame)
    {
        ((DispatcherFrame)frame).Continue = false;
        return null;
    }
```

**The problem:**

I want the Exception thrown in the `ContinueWith()` action to make the test fail. The problem is that `BeginInvoke()` in `CurrentThreadScheduler.QueueTask()` swallows the exception and I can't figure out a way to detect it.

I have tried to subscribe to `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException`, but the event handler never gets called. I have tried to use `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInvoke()` hoping that the exception would propagate, but with no success.

*Needless to say, the code in this question is simplified to demonstrate my problem.*

Comment: I don't think you should be using WPF Dispatcher in unit-testing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9347908/1768303.

Comment: Good point. I thought I needed to use it due to what the production code looks like, but now I see that I only use the Dispatcher in my test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP here.

My debugging skills need to improve (among things). The problem is not `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, but what I do with the result.

This implementation of `QueueTask` solves the problem:

```
protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
{
    var method = new Func<bool>(delegate
        {
            bool success = TryExecuteTask(task);
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invoke", task.Exception);
            }
            return success;
        });
    _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(method);
}
```

Now, listening to `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException` works fine:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;

private void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Assert.Fail("Exception: {0}", e.Exception);
}
```

That said, I agree with @Noseratio's comment that a better solution is not to use WPF Dispatcher in unit test code.