# Unit test IObservable<T> with ObserveOnDispatcher

Tags: c#, linq, reactiveui

I need to test piece of code

```
        var watcher = new FakeIFileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.FilesToBeImported
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(list.Add);
```

so I created this little unit test but I can't make it pass cause list.Count is always 0

```
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        var watcher = new FakeIFileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.FilesToBeImported
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(list.Add);

        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {                
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        Task.WaitAll(task);

        Assert.AreEqual(3, list.Count);
    }
```

if I comment out the method

```
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
```

it pass but how can I get it working also with ObserveOnDispatcher() ?

Comment: What is the value of `list.Count` at failure?

Comment: I solved using the class DispatcherUtil I found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests

Comment: I just want to point out that by having concurrency (implicit or explicit) in your unit tests, you really are limited in what you can do. Here you have both Tasks and a Dispatcher that you have provided no 'seams' in which you can substitute them for a test double (mock/stub). Just as (I assume) you inject a real implementation of IFileSystemWatcher in your prod code, you would inject a SchedulerProvider that gave you real concurreny in prod but test schedulers in you unit tests. Much faster unit tests, easier to test other things like timeouts etc too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the class DispatcherUtil I found here
[Using the WPF Dispatcher in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests)

now my code is the following

```
    [Test]
    public void Foo()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();

        var watcher = new FakeIFileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.FilesToBeImported
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(list.Add);

        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
            watcher.AddFile("cc");
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        Task.WaitAll(task);
        DispatcherUtil.DoEvents();
        Assert.AreEqual(4, list.Count);
    }
```

and it works like a charm

Answer (score 7):

If you use `ObserveOnDispatcher` you create a dependency to the "dispatcher" which means that you need a window and a message loop. To get around this problem in a unit test you can instead use the `ObserveOn` method that uses a scheduler and then use dependency injection to inject the correct scheduler. For unit testing you could use `Scheduler.Immediate` and for the actual application you could use `DispatcherScheduler.Instance`. Notice that there also exists a `TestScheduler` which is really useful for running unit tests in virtual time.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

this line of code  watcher.FilesToBeImported.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(list.Add);
is in my system under test so I can't change it just for the test

Comment: @scott4dev: My point was that you sometimes have to modify your system under test to make it unit testable. E.g. if you access a database you have to create an interface for the database allowing you to stub the database access etc. Your solution avoid this of course.

Comment: you are right, sometimes have to modify your system under test to make it unit testable but in my opinion this not the case. I prefer to use DispatcherUtil.DoEvents(); in my tests and let my SUT in the original state

Answer (score 0):

You can try to invoke your method like this:

```
var dispatcher = Application.Current != null ? Application.Current.Dispatcher : Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

 dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => YourMethodToTest());
```