# Application.Current is null when calling from a unittest

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I have a method that I'm trying to call from a unit test.
This method will in real life be run from a background thread. It uses some code to kick off in the invoke updates to the UI thread (using `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` .... ).

However `Application.Current` is `null` when being called from the unit tests.

I don't really what to put an `if (Application.Current !=null)` around everything to fix.

Is there any other way around this?

_statusUpdates is an ObservableCollection

Below is the part of the code in the method I'm looking to test (it is more of an integration test than a unit test to be fair).

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (EventHandler)delegate
{
    _statusUpdates.Add(new StatusUpdate
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now,
        Message = "Checking For Messages"
    });
}, null, null);
```

Comment: @SonerGonul :-) You correct all questions man. You're a fine person

Comment: If you're doing a unit test, is that Application ever being instantiated? Usually I run into a problem like this if the application is just being started up or shut down (and the application hasn't been built yet, or has already been destroyed).

Comment: @sircodesalot Yes that is the problem Application.current is null, as I'm running from test. Is there any way I can force it to instantiate or something, rather than adding a load of checks for !=null all over the place?

Comment: D'oh I think my question is a duplicate. Sorry:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests

Comment: @Aniket I wish not to but people who new in SO they don't read [faq] and [ask] clearly or they don't know/care about formatting. A question with good format is **always** getting more attention.

Comment: @SonerGönül Hi, what mistake did I make in formatting?  Let me know so I can ensure I don't do it next time, as I thought I had my formatting correctly done.

Comment: @DermFrench You can check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help link for more formatting details.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes but it won't tell me what I did wrong earlier, as I can only see the version you edited?  I'll have a read of the link anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As already stated, you simply won't have an `Application` class during unit tests.

That said, there's an issue here I think needs addressing - by having code that relies on a defined static property, in your case `Application.Current.Dispatch`, you are now **very** tightly coupled to the specific implementation of that class, namely the WPF `Application` class, where you do not need to be.

Even if you simply wrap the idea of "the current root dispatcher" in a `Singleton`-style class wrapper, now you have a way of decoupling yourself from the vagaries of the `Application` class and dealing directly with what you care about, a `Dispatcher`:

Note, there are MANY MANY ways to write this, I'm just putting up the simplest possible implementation; hence, I will not be doing any multithreaded safety checks, etc.

```
public class RootDispatcherFetcher
{
     private static Dispatcher _rootDispatcher = null;

     public static Dispatcher RootDispatcher
     {
         get 
         {
             _rootDispatcher = _rootDispatcher ??
                 Application.Current != null 
                     ? Application.Current.Dispatcher
                     : new Dispatcher(...);
             return _rootDispatcher;
         }
         // unit tests can get access to this via InternalsVisibleTo
         internal set
         {
             _rootDispatcher = value;
         }
     }
}
```

Ok, now this implementation is only *slightly* better than before, but at least you now have finer control over access to the type and are no longer strictly dependent on the existence of an `Application` instance.

Comment: I disagree with this sentiment.  Application.Current.Dispatcher is going to exist anytime you run a WPF application.  Unless you write code that will be used, say, in a Windows Store App vs a Windows Desktop application, then there is no "tight coupling".  I you are writing code that will be used for a WPF application, accessing static resources like this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: "As already stated, you simply won't have an Application class during unit tests." ... That is not true. If you start an application (in a separate AppDomain) you will have a current application within your Unit tests.

Comment: Also, the reason for using Application.Current.Dispatcher is probably because you need access to UI elements, so not just any dispatcher will do.

Answer (score 29):

The following code snippet works for me:

```
if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null) 
  { new System.Windows.Application { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown }; }
```

IIRC, I had a problem where Application was null using a WPF control embedded in a WinForms application and that code snippet was suggested as a solution to the problem in another question on StackOverflow (sorry, can not find the source). It solves the same problem in unit tests (and I don't believe the ShutdownMode property needs to be explicitly set in that case).

Comment: big fan of this answer.  I put the call in the `[ClassInitialize]` method and it works wonderfully!

Comment: Have to add reference to `PresentationFramework.dll` in unit test project.

Comment: It works well without ShutdownMode (xUnit, .Net Framework 4.7.2).

Comment: Works nice with dotnet5 so far where I want to access `Application.Current.Windows` where I new up a window manually, the reference is updated in that collection.

Answer (score 13):

Use  `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` instead of `Application.Current.Dispatcher`

> Gets the System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher for the thread currently
>   executing and creates a new System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher if one
>   is not already associated with the thread.

Comment: I like this answer, I could write my code in the ViewModel like this:

`private static Dispatcher Dispatcher => Application.Current?.Dispatcher ?? Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`

Then simply reference that wherever needed.

Comment: This worked great. But why the hell are there two of them in the first place?

Comment: @MattGregory WPF app can have multiple UI threads.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski Wait a minute, no it can't!  There's always only one UI thread. But multiple threads in general, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have an Application object in a unit-test runner.  These are usually "console" based applications that simply run and execute non-UI code ("units").

I suggest you don't use a unit test framework to test UI-specific information, I suggest a automated UI testing framework to do that.

Answer (score -1):

So the issue here is that somewhere your Application object has to be created. So you need to find where the `System.Windows.Application` (or some descendent) class is being instantiated.

If the project was built from a template, then you'll probably find this class in the App.xaml file. You just need to make sure that this gets instantiated somehow. Else, search your entire project for an `Application` class, and then you'll have to instantiate it manually. Should fix it.