# Autofac, how to resolve/inject Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac

I need to pass the dispatcher to update the UI:

```
container.RegisterType<Dispatcher>().AsSelf();
container.Register(c => new MyViewModel(c.Resolve<Dispatcher>(), ...some other arguments)).As<IMyViewModel>();
```

But since it's static, when I do `container.Build();` I get this exception:

```
Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 
'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher'.'
```

In my viewmodels I usually use it like `_dispatcher?.Invoke('some code');`.

I thought about removing it from the viewmodels contructors and in them just do `_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`, but since I'm working with threads im not sure if it is the best way to use it.

Comment: Create an interface, say IDispatcher, and add a class that implements it and exposes a few Dispatcher methods. Thanks to that solution you'll be able to write unit tests for code that uses dispatcher.

Comment: I'm sorry isnt Dispatcher already a class from the base libraries of  .net?

Answer (score 2):

By registering a dispatcher by `RegisterType`, Autofac will create a **new instance** of a dispatcher each time you try to resolve it. Since a [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=net-5.0) only has an [`private` parameterless constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,de9b5521d0eff55e), you get the error that there is no accessible constructor. In general, you do not create dispatchers yourself.

> When a Dispatcher is created on a thread, it becomes the **only** Dispatcher that can be associated with the thread, even if the Dispatcher is shut down.
>
> If you attempt to get the CurrentDispatcher for the current thread **and a Dispatcher is not associated with the thread, a Dispatcher will be created. A Dispatcher is also created when you create a DispatcherObject**. If you create a Dispatcher on a background thread, be sure to shut down the dispatcher before exiting the thread.

The dispatcher of the user interface thread can be accessed using [`Application.Current.Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=net-5.0#properties). Since this dispatcher already exists and is a **unique instance**, you have to register this instance as singleton.

```
container.RegisterInstance(Application.Current.Dispatcher).AsSelf();
```

Then you can resolve it anywhere by the type `Dispatcher`, because you registered it `AsSelf`.

```
var dispatcher = container.Resolve<Dispatcher>();
```

---

Regarding unit testing your view models, passing a `Dispatcher` is unfortunate. It does not implement a suitable interface to mock it and is `sealed`, so you can derive it. However, there are solutions:

- [Using the WPF Dispatcher in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106881/using-the-wpf-dispatcher-in-unit-tests)
- [How to Test Code that Uses Singletons like Application.Current.Dispatcher?](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2017/02/15/how-to-test-code-that-uses-singletons-like-application-current-dispatcher/)